# Shorthand for defining scala context bound in trait

Tags: scala, type-erasure, context-bound

In scala abstract class, if you want to define a context bound, you can simply use, e.g. [T: ClassTag] in parameter, however this is not possible in trait:

```
trait Foo[T: ClassTag]

Error:(11, 35) traits cannot have type parameters with context bounds `: ...' nor view bounds `<% ...'
trait Foo[T: ClassTag]
         ^
```

if you define:

```
trait Foo[T] {

  implicit def ctg: ClassTag[T] = implicitly[ClassTag[T]]
}

object Bar extends Foo[Int]
```

then any attempt to read ctg inside Bar will trigger a StackOverflowError, as the implicit parameter becomes tail-recursive.

So what's the best way to allow ctg to be defined in a trait that automatically expose subclasses to context bound?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't a nice way. A context bound is short-hand for an implicit parameter, and traits do not have parameters. That is, when you write:

```
 class Foo[T : ClasTag]
```

The compiler de-sugars your code to:

```
 class Foo[T](implicit ev: ClassTag[T])
```

This is of course not possible with a trait. If you *must* work around this with a trait, you can make the `ClassTag` abstract, and force the class that extends it to implement it:

```
trait Foo[T] {
  implicit def ctg: ClassTag[T]
}

object Bar extends Foo[Int] {
  implicit val ctg = classTag[Int]
}
```

This looks *slightly* better with a class in the middle, so that you don't need to specify `Int` twice when defining `Bar`:

```
trait Foo[T] {
  implicit def ctg: ClassTag[T]
}

class FooImpl[T](implicit val ctg: ClassTag[T]) extends Foo[T]

object Bar extends FooImpl[Int]
```

Comment: Thank you. Sad to know that it's not supported, hope an automatic de-sugaring can become a feature in the future