# "No TypeTag available for" with generics

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-reflect

I have this piece of code currently

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType

case class SpecificMessage(id: String)

trait Deserializers {
  val schema = ScalaReflection
    .schemaFor[SpecificMessage]
    .dataType
    .asInstanceOf[StructType]
}
```

I would like to make it more general with respect to the Message like this:

```scala
trait Deserializers[Message] {
  val schema = ScalaReflection
    .schemaFor[Message]
    .dataType
    .asInstanceOf[StructType]
}
```

However I get the following error: `No TypeTag available for Message`.

How do I solve this? I tried several solutions but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Have you tried `Deserializers[Message: TypeTag]`? (keeping [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37265045/shorthand-for-defining-scala-context-bound-in-trait) in mind)

Comment: traits cannot have type parameters with context bounds ': ...' nor view bounds '<% ...'

Comment: That's what the link says: you'd either have to change it to a class, or add it as a separate `val` or `def` or sth. like that.

Comment: The link mentions ClassTags but I'm having problems with TypeTags. I followed the accepted answer in that thread but still have the problem mentioned in the OP

Comment: @Prassi You should use linked answer with modification: `Foo[T : TypeTag]` instead of `Foo[T : ClassTag]`. If you still experience problems after that then please update your question with your current version of code and current problem.